# Using DLL with C++ class functions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

Question: How can I import in Delphi a DLL function named "IOperation7::SaveAsWavFile"?

Details/Explanation:

I am attempting to write code (in Delphi XE, must also work in D2007) to import functions exported by a third party DLL file. The DLL documentation is C++ specific. I have only limited experience with this kind of thing.

The general approach of course is something like this:

```
interface

function SaveAsWavFile (Handle: Cardinal; FileName: WideString): HResult; stdcall;

implementation

function SaveAsWavFile; external 'SOMELIBRARY.DLL';
```

The situation I've encountered is that the function name in the DLL has embedded double colons. Using DLL Export Viewer (www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html), the exported function name is reported as "IOperation7::SaveAsWavFile".

The Delphi *name* directive seemed like it might help, but the following code results in the runtime error "The procedure entry point IOperation7::SaveAsWavFile could not be located..."

```
function SaveAsWavFile; external 'SOMELIBRARY.DLL' name 'IOperation7::SaveAsWavFile';
```

Variations (single colon, dot) also did not work. I also tried the Delphi *index* directive with the ordinal reported by DLL Export Viewer, to no avail. I didn't expect it to work, as it appeared that each ordinal was being used by multiple functions. Which led me to the next suspicion.

I am uncertain of the significance of the :: characters, but I now suspect they have something to do with an *embedded class* within the DLL. So, if my suspicion is correct, my question above perhaps is better stated as "How can I utilize in Delphi functions within a class contained in a DLL?"

**Edit:**
This is the actual reference from the .h file. I realize it doesn't quite match the code I posted above - I was attempting to keep my posted example simple.

```
virtual /* [helpstring][id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE FdSaveAsWavFile(
/* [in] */ ULONG handle,
/* [in] */ BSTR newFileName,
/* [in] */ ULONG newAudioFormat,
/* [in] */ ULONG failIfExists,
/* [in] */ IOLDMFileProgressNotification *progress) = 0;
```

Comment: I understand that an answer in actual Delphi code may be impossible, as I've probably left out necessary information that I failed to recognize as important. I'll be happy with pointers to decent reference material on the general problem.

Comment: So you're saying that some sad third party decided to leave C++ name mangling as an exercise for the reader, which is you? Are you aware of what a horrific mess C++ class name mangling is, and how much of a pain this is? I suggest you run the MS dumpbin util on the dll and find out what it's really called.   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429?wa=wsignin1.0    ( `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS mydll.dll` ) I consider C++-mangled exports in DLLs to be a sign of incompetence. (Not yours, whoever wrote that DLL.)  Also it's not going to be WideString (that's a Delphi type). Post the .hpp class declaration.

Comment: @Warren WideString is nothing more than COM BSTR

Comment: That looks awfully like a function on an interface. I'd start from the C++ header file.

Comment: Oh so do you think it's a COM Interface maybe or a native C++ interface? Hard to guess. Eric your question is unanswerable unless you post a relevant snippet of the C++ class declaration.

Comment: I do have a .h header file. It's a bit over 37,000 lines long. I've tried three different automated converters on it. Obviously one can't expect perfect results from such tools, but they've produced little more than gibberish from this file.

Comment: You want one function. No need to convert 37000 lines of code. Do show the other side of the interface so we don't have to guess.

Comment: You should also post the context of that"FdSave..."method. If it's a member of a class or interface. Not all the whole file. In programming CONTEXT (LEXICAL SCOPE) is VERY IMPORTANT. It's possible that this is a COM TYPE LIBRARY INTERFACE which you would import as a type library.

Comment: After further review of the SDK documentation and communication with the provider, we've confirmed that this is indeed a COM interface (unlike the other SDK from them that I implemented recently). I have successfully imported/created the _tlb type library file and am finally making some progress on the project. Thank you everyone for your input and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a C++ class that is exported by the DLL then you'll need to write a C++ wrapper DLL to convert it to something that can be consumed by Delphi. That's because C++ classes can only be consumed by C++ code in just the same way that Delphi classes can only be consumed by Delphi code.

If this is an interface then you may be able to use the DLL directly. If the interface is COM compatible then you may be in better shape. You need to know how to instantiate the objects though. Is it COM? Or do you call functions exported by the DLL?

You will get nowhere trying to guess at this with PE viewer. You need to study the DLL's documentation and header file. That is the true specification for the binary interface.

---

Regarding your update, that looks like the method from an interface. That's what interface methods look like. But, there's still not enough information to say for sure.

Comment: On Monday when my brain is fresh I'll review the contents of the SDK to see if I can spot a wrapper dll. Could be tricky as the SDK is only half the equation - it also requires the commercial software that the SDK is for to be installed (the SDK is based on DLLs that aren't included in the SDK, which has been a big source of irritation for me). The upshot is that with the default installation paths there are DLLs in at least 4 completely different locations that I've found so far.

Comment: Surely the documentation of this thing, whatever it is (why don't you tell us?), tell you how to call it. Is it a COM interface? Is it a C++ interface? I still thing you are wasting your time looking for DLLs. Use the SDK, header files, documentation. The DLLs are implementation detail that you may need to know later. First up, work out what this thing is.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to hide the SDK, I was just trying to pare the question down to the least-amount-of-fluff details. The SDK is FileDownloadSDK_v206. This is from Olympus, for their handheld digital recorders (used in transcription). I was able to get another of their related SDKs (DSS&DSSProSDK_v200) working in Delphi with relatively little difficulty. But it didn't have this double-colon "IOperation7::SaveAsWavFile" format for the DLL exports, and the .h file was much more straightforward.